# ESP32 communication with tablet using SerialPort-USB in react-native / expo

Tags: react-native, expo, serial-port, esp32

I have a project that is already working with ESP32, expo and firebase. But it adds a unecessary cost for my project, since ESP32 and the tablet are really close in my project and the wifi is not stable. So I thought I could just send the data from USB. It would also avoid the need to have two chargers. Is it possible?

Sorry if its a well known issue, but everywhere I look I just found solutions with BLE, that's not a option for many reasons.

Note: It only have to work with android, and I found some solutions with flutter, that I would like to not use, since my react-native code is already done

The wifi solution is already working. I'm new to frontend, react-native and expo, so I really don't know if it's possible, and where to look for the solution. I've tried some solutions using AI, but then I discovered my phone does not support OTG and cant check if it works. So I want to know if its possible before I buy the tablet.